# How to apply background color to listview dynamically in Android?

Tags: android

How to apply background color to listview dynamically in [Android](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_%28operating_system%29)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure what it is you want to do but one of [`View.setBackgroundColor()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundColor(int)), [`View.setBackgroundDrawable()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)) or [`View.setBackgroundResource`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource(int)) should cover it, depending on what you want to show.

Remember, each item in a `ListView` is a `View` in its own right, so depending on how you're creating them, they may be obscuring the background you're setting for your `ListView`.

You may also need to disable the cache color hint to get your views to display how you want.  Have a look at [this post of the Android Developer's Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/why-is-my-list-black-android.html) for more information.